# When does EntityManager::lock() even have sense?

Tags: php, symfony, concurrency, doctrine

Working with Symfony 5.4 and Doctrine, I have an entity which I need to update with concurrency safety in mind. I need to add balance to existing balance and avoid stale data if 2 requests come at the same time.

This is my controller:

```php
#[Route('/{id}/add10ToBalance', name: 'cp_partners_resellers_edit')]
public function add10ToBalance(Request $request, Reseller $reseller): Response
```

and as you can see the `Reseller` entity is loaded from the URL.

Now that i have the entity, I do:

```php
$this->entityManager->getConnection()->beginTransaction(); // suspend auto-commit

try {
    $this->entityManager->lock($reseller, LockMode::PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);

    $reseller->setBalance($reseller->getBalance() + 10);

    $this->entityManager->persist($reseller);
    $this->entityManager->flush();

    $this->entityManager->getConnection()->commit();
```

I confirmed from SQL log in debugger that this issues following sequence:

```sql
SELECT * FROM reseller WHERE id = ?
START TRANSACTION
SELECT 1 FROM reseller t0 WHERE t0.id = ? FOR UPDATE
UPDATE reseller SET balance = ? WHERE id = ?
COMMIT
```

The issue seems clear here - the `lock()` function does not actually refresh data from the DB. So between the `SELECT` and `START TRANSACTION` if the entity gets modified, I am now working with a locked version in DB, but the data I have in my Symfony process is stale.

The obvious solution is to use

```php
$reseller = $this->entityManager->find(Reseller::class, $reseller->getId(), LockMode::PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
```

on top, which leads to correct SQL order:

```sql
SELECT * FROM reseller WHERE id = ?
START TRANSACTION
SELECT * FROM reseller WHERE id = ? FOR UPDATE
UPDATE reseller SET balance = ? WHERE id = ?
COMMIT
```

But then it makes me wonder:

**What is even the real use of the `EntityManager::lock()` method, if it leads to locking potentially stale data?**

Comment: Have you considered using optimistic locking instead? You can specify a version field on your entity and then query/update with the last known version. Doctrine will then block you from updating your entity if a newer version exists. It sounds like this is what you are looking for. Pessimistic locking is really more suited for cases where you have fresh data and want to prevent it from becoming stale by blocking other changes, rather than preventing potential stale data from overwriting other changes

Comment: EntityManager::lock() literally does what it says, it locks that entity. Use cases could be, that you're not really interested in what's in the database, just that you want to be the only one being able to write on it. For example to specify a reseller.last_transaction timestamp or whatever. So there are use cases, they might seem forced though ...

Comment: @dbrumann optimistic locking is not what I need in this case. I have simplified the example a lot to show the principle, but I am working with financial application working with balances across multiple tables. I really do not wish for the command to fail in case of optimistic lock being outdated, I want DB level locking so that I am sure my values are not even loaded on other places whilst I manipulate them. For now the workaround with find() works just fine, but I opened a PR to extend the refresh() method to support locking, which is what I need - https://github.com/doctrine/orm/pull/10040